# How to use existing keras model in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I have Keras model which I have converted to tensorflow.js but could not load the model in javascript, what will be the steps for that?

```
model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, seq_len, input_length=seq_len))
model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(vocabulary_size, activation='softmax'))
# compiling the network
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_inputs,train_targets,epochs=256,verbose=1)
```

Comment: Is the model saved on local storage?

Comment: Yes, I have converted it into tensorflow.js and saved locally.

Comment: Is the application in plain javascript or a framework like in React?

Comment: Yes I have created it in React and I have created one server using express which holds my model so from that server I am taking my model but I am not getting any success, am I following the right path?

Comment: Ah so you are using a HTTPs request to load the model. I will add an answer shortly. What is the URL to the saved model? I mean the `model.json`

Comment: 'http://localhost:81/tfjs-models/model.json' I am using this URL.

Comment: I searched a lot and found that we can not load the model from local storage so I did this, but somehow I am not still able to load the model.

Comment: Could you please show your react code ?

Comment: `import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs/';
import { useState } from 'react';
import  '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl'
const CardComponent = () => {
sync function loadModel(){
    const handler = ('http://localhost:81/tfjs-models/model.json');
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);
    console.log("Model loaded");
}


loadModel();
`

Comment: @Shivanshi did you try my answer?

Comment: @yudhiesh I am just trying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the model from an endpoint like so.

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const url = {
    model: 'http://localhost:81/tfjs-models/model.json',
};

async function loadModel(url) {
  try {
    // For layered model
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(url.model);
    // For graph model
    // const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(url.model);
    setModel(model);
    console.log("Load model success");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
} 
const [model, setModel] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  tf.ready().then(() => {
    loadModel(url);
  });
}, []);
```

The model can then be accessed by using the `model` from state.

Comment: I did console.log(model.Summary()) and got this :TypeError: webglBackend.incRef is not a function, is it an issue to be resolved?

Comment: What does `console.log(model)` output?

Comment: TypeError: webglBackend.incRef is not a function
at reshape (Reshape.ts:50)
 at Object.min [as kernelFunc] (Min.ts:48)
    at h (engine.js:562)
    at engine.js:619
    at t.e.scopedRun (engine.js:436)
    at t.e.runKernelFunc (engine.js:616)
    at t.e.runKernel (engine.js:494)
    at min_ (min.ts:64)
    at Module.min__op (operation.ts:51)
    at Module.min (math_utils.ts:74)
    at new LSTMCell (recurrent.ts:1663)
    at new LSTM (recurrent.ts:1856)
    at fromConfig (recurrent.ts:1886)
    at deserializeKerasObject (generic_utils.ts:277)
    at deserialize .....

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake try `if(model) {console.log(model)}` and what version of TFJS are you using?

Comment: 3.0.0 is the version

Comment: Does it work? Also please include the list of dependencies from `package.json` in the question. I also changed the imports try the updated answer.

Comment: still getting the same typeError

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^3.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^3.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^3.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },

Comment: Tried it, I am really not sure why am I getting this typeError.

Comment: Yeah it is strange try creating an issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues).

Comment: Added the issue, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Could you also try downgrading to Tensorflow.js 2.8?

Comment: Yes done but still same error, any idea what possibly could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflowjs as tfjs

model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, seq_len, input_length=seq_len))
model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(vocabulary_size, activation='softmax'))
# compiling the network
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_inputs,train_targets,epochs=256,verbose=1)

# save the model in model.json

tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, './keras_converted')
```

Load the model in javascript

- To load the model.json in the browser, it has to be served in a local server since the brower cannot access directly the filesystem

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://hostname:port/path/to/model.json');
```